# Elastic search: java.net.ConnectException when connecting via RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, indexing

I am able to access the ElasticSearch via  http://127.0.0.1:9200, however when trying to connect from the same machine via RestHighLevelClient I get the java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.

```html
try {
        final BulkResponse response=this.restHighLevelClient.bulk(bulkRequest);
}
catch (final IOException exn) {
        LOG.error("Bulk insert failed", exn);
    
}
```

The configuration class for Elastic search client is like below.

```html
@Bean
public RestHighLevelClient restClient() {
return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", "9200", "http")));
}
```

I have retained the default settings in elastic-search.yml file and debugged to be sure that host and port are correct.
Any ideas please?

Comment: Share the code you used to create `restHighLevelClient`

Comment: Edited and included the client config.

Comment: `CONNECTION REFUSED` is the TCP error you will see when there is no application listening to the selected  port. Check to see that you actually have a program running and bound to port 9200.

Comment: What if you pass host value as `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but my problem was that I was connecting to the wrong host by mistake.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. neither localhost nor 127.0.0.1 seems to work.